# Calling Powershell script from PHP is not working

Tags: javascript, php, powershell

I need to use a powershell script within my PHP code. Javascript code calls a PHP file and waits for the response, the PHP code calls my powershell script and returns a value. 
This works fine when I run PHP alone which calls powershell script. 
This also works fine when I simply print a value in runpm.php commenting shell_exec() command. So I assume the problem is with the Shell_exec() command. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

javascript code:

```
var myLink = document.getElementById('btn');

    var php_var = "<?php echo $dest_path; ?>";

    myLink.onclick = function(){

         try{       


    var pingtext = document.getElementById('ping');

    var ping = document.getElementById('btn');
    ping.style.backgroundColor = "#5bc0de";
    ping.style.visibility='hidden';       

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            if (this.responseText == 1) {
                alert(this.responseText);
               ping.style.visibility='visible';
                ping.style.backgroundColor = "green"; 
                ping.innerHTML='Import Success' ; 
                ping.style.width='80px';  
                ping.style.marginLeft='10%';          
                pingtext.innerHTML = '';
            } else {
                alert("error");
                ping.style.visibility='visible';
                ping.style.display='block';
                ping.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                ping.innerHTML='Failed' ; 
                ping.style.width='80px';
                ping.style.marginLeft='25%'; 
                pingtext.innerHTML = '';
            }
        }
    };

    pingtext.innerHTML = "<img src=\"gentel/production/images/loadingspinner.gif\" width=\"30px\">";
    xmlhttp.open("Get", "runpm.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}catch(e){
    console.error(e);
}
```

runpm.php:

```
<?php


    $psoutput = shell_exec('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\retailPlanning\testpsscript.ps1"');
    echo "$psoutput"

?>
```

testpsscript.ps1:

```
cls
echo "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

What the web server do you use?

If it is Apache, you can try to run this service as non-default user. To do it go to `services.msc`, find Apache service, click Properties, find  Log On tab and set some other account (username and password). Do not forget to restart service.

If it is not Apache, you can try to do similar steps with any other web server.

Comment: I use windows server, configured php with iis, not sure for which server to add logon..

Comment: Try to do it with IIS service

Comment: Did the same, found the service - World Wide Web Publishing Service service and added logon. but when I restart, got the following error - 'Windows could not start the World Wide Web Publishing Service service on Local Computer
Error 1079: The account specified for this service is different from the account specified for other services running in the same process'. I had to revert the change back to restart the service